# How can I flatten out a list that contains another list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects which are described below.  Inside this are `IKanji` objects.

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}
```

Where each object contains a list of `IKanji` objects

```
public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}

List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> entries = dictionary.GetEntries().ToList();
```

Can someone show me how it's possible to get a list of all the Text values in the Kanjis lists?

In other words if there are two objects in entries and the first has a Kanjis list with three entries and the second a Kanjis list with two entries then what I would like to see is a list containing 5 rows of Kanji.Text   Another way to explain it would be that I want to see a single list of every Kanji.Text in `entries`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SelectMany` method to flatten multiple lists into a single list.  In this case, you could do something like this:

```
var items = dictionary.GetEntries()
                      .SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
                      .Select(x => x.Text)
```